# How do I check an unknown amount of inputs java and stop checking at the end of a line

Tags: java, input

This is my first question. I am a second year computer science student and I'm having some trouble reading several inputs correctly. I'm creating a board game that accepts a line of commands.

This is what some of the problem code looks like:

User is asked to input a command like that could look like this: `create 0 0 fast flexible`, or like this: `create 0 0`, with the integers being of any value and fast or flexible being able to be entered without the other.

```
if((keyboard.next()).equals("create"))
{
    xValue = keyboard.nextInt();
    yValue = keyboard.nextInt();

if((keyboard.next().equals("fast")))
{
        pieceType = "FP";
        if((keyboard.next().equals("flexible")))
        {
            pieceType = "FF";
        }
    }


if((keyboard.next().equals("flexible")))
{
        pieceType = "SF";
        if((keyboard.next().equals("fast")))
        {
            pieceType = "FF";
        }
}
}
```

The program consistently wants 7 inputs.

How do I make it stop checking for inputs after the user presses enter?

Comment: You really should be using an enum in this case (instead of `pieceType = ""`).

Comment: The program requires 7 inputs because that's what you made it do. You should replace your 7 `keyboard.next()` calls with reading only one line, then split it at `space` sign and after that check for the right tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could split the whole string according to the white-spaces and then process the string sequentially by words (or parts). Anyway, you should assert the input as a whole carefully.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
String NEW_LINE_SIGN = "\n";
if (keyboard.next().contains(NEW_LINE_SIGN){ /* .... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
kbd.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
//you could create a rule automatically with some kind of a rules engine
if(kbd.hasNext("create(\\s+)(\\d+)(\\s+)(\\d+)(\\s+)(fast|flexible)(\\s+)(fast|flexible)")) {
    MatchResult res = kbd.match();
    for(int i = 0; i <= res.groupCount(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(res.group(i));
        //handleRules(res.group(i), i);
    }
}
kbd.close();
```